# Floating point on Cam Tables?

Tags: programming, servo, floating-point

What's the general way to handle floating point error on a cam table?  Constraints are using:

- PLC Open function blocks
- Scale on application units for servo setup
  is an `int`

So lets say the application units used are 360 degrees on a servo.  I have to set the basic application unit to a whole number because of the `int` constraint. Based on the system every 360 degrees on the master should be 6.3864573044041 degrees on the slave.

This means I'd have a cam table like this:

[image: CamTable]

I'm going to have issues with the period of the slave not being a factor of 360, and an issue with floating point error (my numbers will offset incrementally by small amounts every period due to the truncation of numbers after the decimal).

How is this usually handled?  It seems crazy to me that I would need to redesign the system to fix a programming issue.  I figure someone out there must have a lot of experience in this.